# Why Boolean State does not change with hook?

Tags: flutter, hook

How To Toggle value using Hook? I have tried this code but the state never chanched.

**The Code Is:**

```
class ExampleScreen extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var toggleValue = useState(false);
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: Checkbox(
                    value: toggleValue .value,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      toggleValue.value !=  toggleValue.value;
                      print("\n toggleValue ${ toggleValue .value}\n");
                    },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does HookWidget extends StatefulWidget?

Comment: a kinda. @VictorKwok

Comment: this is the library. @VictorKwok
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the value returned from the onChanged callback to assign the new value. The new value is not automatically assigned to the ValueNotifier.value.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var toggleValue = useState(false);
    return Scaffold(
        body: Checkbox(
          value: toggleValue.value,
          onChanged: (value) {
            toggleValue.value = value!;
            print("\n toggleValue $value\n");
          },
        )
    );
  }
```

Comment: does not work, both are the same

Comment: @winter please check my updated answer

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/